# Can a security system detect there are multiple copies of a single-issued fob?

Tags: authentication, rfid

My building gave me a single fob. I made 3 copies of it for my family and they all opened the building entrance but not my actual apartment door, until one day the building told me they had noticed I had made copies of the fobs which was not allowed. They gave me a new fob and all previous fobs stopped working. How did they find out? And why did the copies not open my apartment door? It's one of those droplet-shaped thin fobs.

Comment: There will be logs at the admin with details of each fob and timestamp etc.  If its a half-decent software, it will flag unknow fobs.  The admin software also controls what each fob is allowed to do.  This, again will be based on its id.

Comment: Google search: "how to detect a cloned rfid fob"

Comment: How did you make multiple copies? By coping and hardcoding the signal into others?

Comment: It would help if the exact technology of the fob in question was known. MIFARE Classic? Some other?

Answer (score 4):

There have been different methods of detecting cloned RFID fobs developed over the years depending on the complexity of the system:

- [a random number](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0193951) added to the fob that gets changed with every successful authentication - a cloned (or original) tag will not get updated with the new random number after first use
- the tracking of the combination of a [TagID and RFID chip serial number](https://www.rfidjournal.com/question/can-every-rfid-card-be-copied-or-cloned) (which cannot be changed)
- or simple access pattern anomaly detection (e.g. fob used to enter twice without an exit event in the logs, etc.)

All of these located with the Google search: "how to detect a cloned rfid fob"

Without more information, it is not possible to determine why some doors worked and some didn't. In the past, some outside access doors were not hooked up to the authentication system, but merely looked for a compatible key (a key made by the same manufacturer as the reader).

Comment: TagId and CSN can be changed on some chips. - especially on the kind used to make clones.

Comment: Depending on the system, yes. Any hardware can be created to expose any number of functions.

Answer (score -1):

If the fob can be written by the readers a sufficiently complex system can use cookies to learn that there are now three tokens claiming the same ID.

Comment: cookies? on a hardware fob? Can you provide a reference to such an idea?

Comment: as a reference I'll point to your answer above "a random number"  that's an example of a cookie.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible.  If the fob contains a counter which is incremented on each request, it's possible to detect that a copy has been made.

For example, say the original fob's counter is 5, and a copy is made.  The original fob is used again twice, and each time the counter is incremented so that it's now 7.  If the copy is used, its counter will be 6, which is less, which indicates that either the fob has been copied or an attacker is attempting to replay an earlier message.

Using a counter like this in conjunction with a suitable MAC, AEAD, or digital signature can be used to prevent replay attacks.  This is valuable because it prevents someone from loitering outside your apartment building, recording the data sent by the fob, and then later on using it to open the building or your apartment.  Of course, it also prevents you from copying the fob unnoticed.

Other implementations more complex than a counter can also be used as well.

Comment: This is an interesting idea but I'm not sure that RFID tags have a counter nor can they accommodate one. I tried to verify and nothing is coming up to support this idea. Can you provide a reference? Plus, how would the fob determine that the power it gets is from the building's RFID system and not any other system?

Comment: @schroeder Not sure I understand your comment. RFID tags support encryption and authentication and has storage - essentially [smart cards](https://spy-fy.com/how-does-a-rfid-card-work/) with RFID and not contact interface.

Comment: @vidarlo yes, I understand, but the context here is a building's "teardrop" RFID fob. I can find no reference to a "counter" functionality. And the problem with using a counter, if it is indeed included, makes. no sense. All I'm asking for is a reference to the assertion because in my curiousity, I cannot find one.

Comment: I grok. They're commonly [Mifare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIFARE) or similar, which allows authenticated writes, which *can* be used for a counter.